# Image positionning issue in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having an alignment problem while using `SwiftUI`.
Maybe I should say a layout issue. Anyway here is the situation:

This is the relevant part of the app interface:

[image]

One can see that while the text ("+++++") is centered, the flag is not. It is slightly shifted to the left. This left-shifting is precisely my problem. I would like the image to be centered as the text is.

Here follows the code, I would like to know what I am doing wrong for the image not to be centered:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TheNiceView: View {
    ........

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                TheButtonView()
                Spacer()
            }

            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {})
                {
                    Text("+++++")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TheButtonView: View {
    ........
    let imgSide:CGFloat = 72.0

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {})
            {
                Image(uiImage: ThaiFlagImg)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: imgSide, height: imgSide)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case this may be useful, this is the image used for the flag:

[image]

Comment: Maybe your `ThaiFlagImg` image itself is off center? But try attaching `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` to the image too.

Comment: For reference I've added the image used for the flag. You can check that it is not off center. I also tried your suggestion of attaching .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit), but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Maybe it's related to your way to create the UIImage. If you add this image file  to the Asset Catalog and use it directly the layout is correct.

Comment: As @vadian also mentioned, tried your code this image being added to Asset Catalog. The image is centered properly

Answer (score 0):

#### 1

Thailand flag has **five** horizontal stripes in the colours red, white, blue, white and red. The image you use has 7 srtips.

#### 2

Using the `Spacers` and `HStack` are unnecessary.

I used the following image without the `Spacers` and `HStack`, both the +++ button and the flag are aligned in the center.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Flag_of_Thailand.svg

```
struct TheNiceView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TheButtonView()
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("+++++")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TheButtonView: View {
    let imgSide:CGFloat = 72.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}){
            Image( "ThaiFlagImg")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: imgSide, height: imgSide)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to see how you do, removing the Spacers and HStack; but I still get the flag left shifted. I do not use the Asset Catalog, the image file is simply added to the project. By the way why having Spacers and HStack would be a problem?

Comment: After a bit more work I also managed to get rid of the left-shift (as you do).
But I need to understand why there is a problem with Spacers and HStack. Because when I want to have 2 or 3 images one beside the other I will need an HStack to group them and at this point, if I use an HStack the shift comes back.

Comment: @Michel It is not a PROBLEM to use HStack and Spacer. It is redundant because you have a single View. If you have multiple views, you need to use them.

Comment: @michal How  is it added? I bet either the image has white vertical srtip  or there is a padding or Spacer on its right side.

Comment: Please read my last comment for the answer to this question. The image has no white vertical strip, you can check it in the post.